# How to display context sensitive help for our own wizard?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have made two wizard pages in eclipse plugin, actually i added another project type, called MyProject, so when the user does New->MyProject (Similar to New->Java) , the wizard page for MyProject appears. This MyProject has two pages, fill page1 and hit Next you go to page2. I added the context help in **public void createControl(Composite parent)**  of the page that creates the wizard page by using, {First line for page1.java and second line for page2.java}

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(parent, "my.plugin.id.context_id_page1");
```

and

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(parent, "my.plugin.id.context_id_page2");
```

The Plugin.xml has:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
      <contexts
            file="contexts.xml"
            plugin="my.plugin.id">
      </contexts>
   </extension>
```

And the contexts.xml has:

```
<contexts>
   <context id="my.plugin.id.context_id_page1">
      <description>This wizard helps you in creating MyProject.</description>
      <topic href="http://www.google.com" label="Google it!" />
   </context>
   <context id="my.plugin.id.context_id_page2">
          <description>This wizard helps you in creating MyProject Page2.</description>
          <topic href="http://www.google.com" label="Google it!" />
   </context>
</contexts>
```

The Help appears when i use F1 or the question mark on left side, but if i go to page2 and then come back page1, the help does not appear!
That is,
New->MyProject, in Page1 and Page2 for first time it works, now if i navigate backwards, the context help does not work!
How to resolve this?
And all other functionalities are working fine!
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to set the help on the `Composite` you create for the wizard page, **not** on the parent composite.

You could use:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(getControl(), "context id");
```

may sure this is after the call to `setControl()`.

Comment: it helped, but there is still a problem that when i hit back, then the help does not change till i focus on one of the fields. You get to know about this, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Try overriding `public void setVisible(final boolean visible)` in the wizard page and do a set focus when the page becomes visible.